# Can joblib in sklearn.externals be used joblib.dump() in 64bit and load it in 32 bit using joblib.load()

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, joblib

I would train a classifier using scikit learn in ubuntu  64bit and store it using joblib in sklearn.externals but when i load it in raspbian a 32bit system it commits an error a value error

Comment: Are you using the same version of python in both cases ?

Comment: I am having the same issue.How did you solve it?